# Combining a neural network classifier with genetic algorithm to do the task likes what generative adversarial network does?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, generative-adversarial-network

Recently I read some materials about GANs(Generative adversarial network). I know that GANs uses a discriminator network to distinguish the expected output(let's say that it's an image),and a generative network to be trained to generate the expected output.

What I wonder is that, is it possible to combine a neural network classifier with genetic algorithm to do the similar task GANs does?

For example, with an image classifier which takes an image as input and outputs the possibility that the image is a cat image (like what a discriminator network does), and with genetic algorithm which uses image as its chromosome and the output of the classifier as its fitness function.

Can we use the approach I described above to do the task similar to what GANs does? does there exist any researches which is similar to this idea?